# Not able to get sum and corresponding column values into row of a dataframe

Tags: r, data-science

From the huge data set I have extracted below data,

```
Short.name   |          Date  | Utilization|count |hour
1  XYX-cNum0 |X15.05.19..00.00|      75.57 |    1 |  00
2  ABC-cNum1 |X15.05.19..00.00|      96.08 |    1 |  00
3 DEF-cNum11 |X15.05.19..00.00|      96.01 |    1 |  00
4 ZEF-cNum12 |X15.05.19..00.00|      68.68 |    0 |  00
5 ABC1-cNum13|X15.05.19..00.00|      98.17 |    1 |  00
6 ABC-cNum14 |X15.05.19..00.00|      92.56 |    1 |  00
```

from above I have to get output as *sum of count* having value as 1 and then populate all *Short.name* against the sum count in rows
please note hour value is 00 to 23

I have tried below code for output:

```
#Reading the Data in "dat" object
base_data<-read.csv(filelocation,header = TRUE,sep=",")

data_trim<-base_data[,-c(1,3,4,5,6)]

#Data cleansing

library(tidyr)
#Getting required information in the format
gather_data <- data_trim %>% gather(Date,Utlization,-`Short.name`)

#Setting bollean value for finding > 70 utilization and storing in count
gather_data$count <- ifelse(gather_data$Utlization> 70,1,0)

#Extracting hour information from the date and storing in column hour
gather_data$hour<-substr(gather_data$Date, 12, 13)


#Function defination to get the sum and column values
extractShrtName<-function(df,ht){
  count_sum<-subset(df,hour == ht & count == 1)
  row_value<-count_sum[,1]
  ln<-length(which(count_sum$count==1))
  return(row_value,ln)
}`

extractShrtName(gather_data,"00")

hour|countofcells|celllist          
00  |   893      |XYX-cNum0|ABC-cNum1|...till 893 cell list
14  |   113      |List of all 113 cells
6   |   85       |List of 85 cell
```

Comment: Apologies I was not able to get the data structured while asking the question.Lost format once posted

Comment: You can edit a post using the `edit` button at the bottom left of the question.